# How to create and organize a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8 and jQuery 1.8.

I have some info coming out of a database and being populated into divs like this:

```
<div class='SpecInfo' data-height='10' data-width='23' data-length='156'></div>
<div class='SpecInfo' data-height='20' data-width='21' data-length='159'></div>
<div class='SpecInfo' data-height='30' data-width='25' data-length='154'></div>
<div class='SpecInfo' data-height='40' data-width='27' data-length='155'></div>
<input type='button' id='GoButton' value='Go!'>
```

I need to pull out that information and put it into an array and pass it to a CFC.  I have a function that collects the data.  It looks like this:

```
// SET VARS
$GoButton = $("#GoButton"),
    SpecArray = {
        Height: [],
        Width: [],
        Length: []
    };

// GO
var go = function() {
    var $SpecInfo = $(".SpecInfo"),
        SpecInfoLen = $SpecInfo.length,
        H, 
        W,
        L;
    for (i = 0; i < SpecInfoLen; i++) {
        var H = $SpecInfo.eq(i).data('height'),
            W = $SpecInfo.eq(i).data('width'),
            L = $SpecInfo.eq(i).data('length');
        // add H,W,L values to spec array
        SpecArray['Height'].push(H);
        SpecArray['Width'].push(W);
        SpecArray['Length'].push(L);
    }
    // stringify spec array
    // pass spec array to cfc
    alert(SpecArray['Height'].length);
}
$GoButton.click(go);
```

What this gives me is an array of heights, an array of widths, and an array of lengths.  This is not what I want. My info is organized like this

```
[10,20,30,40]
[23,21,25,27]
[156,159,154,155]
```

For each div, I want all of the attributes in a single place.  I want something more like this:

```
[10,23,156]
[20,21,159]
[30,25,154]
[40,27,155]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I organize my array?

Comment: If you're not modifying the data client-side, the other possible way of achieving this is to use SerializeJSON() on the query and send that to the client,as well as the HTML representation. That way you don't have to scrape the DOM for the data to send back later. Admittedly, the serialized Query probably won't be in the right form, but I think CF will convert it back into a query object on the  server, which may be handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So why do you put all the data in 3 separate arrays instead of an array of objects?

Instead of

```
    SpecArray['Height'].push(H);
    SpecArray['Width'].push(W);
    SpecArray['Length'].push(L);
```

use

```
    SpecArray.push( { 'height': H, 'width': W, 'length': L } );
```

This results in an array of objects like the following:

```
[
 { 'height': 10, 'width': 23, 'length': 156 },
 { 'height': 20, 'width': 21, 'length': 159 },
 { 'height': 30, 'width': 25, 'length': 154 },
 { 'height': 40, 'width': 27, 'length': 155 }
]
```

You have to init `SpecArray` as an array, though, and not as an object containing 3 arrays.

Comment: Can you clarify this? "You have to init SpecArray as an array, though, and not as an object containing 3 arrays."  I have seen many examples of DO NOT CREATE AN ARRAY THIS WAY. What would be the RIGHT way to create this array?

Comment: @EvikJames Just use `var SpecArray = [];` instead of `SpecArray = { Height: [], Width: [], Length: [] };`. Besides the last `alert()` call your code should be fine then.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just couldn't get my brain to think about this the right way. I appreciate your time and knowledge.